# Шрифт в Code Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Как поменять шрифт в консольной програме во время выполнение программы на "Luida Console". Я использую Code Blocks.

Comment: Вы хотите из своей программы менять шрифт в IDE?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov нет. Во время выполнения программы, в консольном окне.

Comment: Тогда причём здесь Code Blocks? И позвольте пользователю самому выбирать шрифт в своей консоли: у кого плохое зрение - поставит шрифт побольше и т. п.

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov по условию задания менять шрифт программно. В Visual Studio есть некотерая функция, но я ни знаю есть ли в Code Blocks

Comment: Функция не в IDE, она в языке! Что за функция в VS? Приведите её название.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov а точнее в *.h-файлах.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39818/discussion-between--and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из обсуждения в чате выяснилось, что используется GCC.

Изменить шрифт в консоли Windows можно функцией `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`. Она находится в библиотеке `KERNEL32.DLL`. Можно подключить её динамически. Кроме того, определим структуру `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`, необходимую для задания параметров шрифта.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef struct _CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX {
    ULONG cbSize;
    DWORD nFont;
    COORD dwFontSize;
    UINT  FontFamily;
    UINT  FontWeight;
    WCHAR FaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
} CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX, *PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *SETCURRENTCONSOLEFONTEX)(HANDLE, BOOL, PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
SETCURRENTCONSOLEFONTEX SetCurrentConsoleFontEx;

int main()
{
    HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandle("KERNEL32.DLL");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx = (SETCURRENTCONSOLEFONTEX)GetProcAddress(hmod, "SetCurrentConsoleFontEx");
    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx) {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font;
    ZeroMemory(&font, sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX));
    font.cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    wcscpy(font.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");
    font.dwFontSize.X = 10;
    font.dwFontSize.Y = 16;

    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false, &font)) {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        exit(2);
    }

    std::cout << "Hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```